# Unreachable network after restart

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ip

I have a machine with duel boot

windows loads network perfectly

ubuntustudio 22.04.1 LTS Don't

however I could use `sudo netdiscover` to see my router ip

browsers can't open it's page or surfe the internet

ping gives `network unreachable` with IPs and `temporary failer in name resolution` with domains

network manager is keeping attaching and deattaching network with `IP configuration was unavailable`

[image]

[image]

- I tried reseting router and no efect
- then tried re-installing ubuntu however I noticed that the network have the same behavior from the live session *_*
- I tried adding default route to my interface and now pinging ip is go throgh network but with 100% packet lose

[image]

- once rebooting to windows; network  is fine !_!

### I'm confused..

Every thing happened today, no updates or changes done before closing the system yesterday

Any body could help me tweak over this problem ? No answer on the web or within my mind helped..

### I can't surf the internet with the ubuntu (only) on my machine

the sitiuation now is that the pc could discover IP of router but can't resolve, ping or query domains.. it's connected using cat 6 eth cable 3 meters to the router, the same pc has another hard disk to boot with windows, and windows has no problem at all about connection.. actually my brother should be useing windows now to attend a video class.. the problem is with handling connection from only ubuntu lan and wan, even from the installed system or live iso,

### Edits:

1: I followed some instructions and now I'm able to see router interface and ping it after restart, but not surfing the internet

2: I could now recall what cased that.. I noticed that the terminal is now no longer give output in my local language but in english.. I tried instailling ubuntu (no live session) on a USB stick before restarting the time I found this problem.. seems it reverted to my system environment rather than just stopping at the USB stick

anyway this seems to break my networks somehow, while all network configuration files are the same, but config itself has changed, same as locales on my system

3: add lspci and journalctl output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Open a terminal and enter command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`. Then enter the command `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep  linux-firmware` Then copy the output of both commands using mouse and paste it directly into [your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1440377/edit). Format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window. In general please don't put screenshots of the terminal in the question. Always copy and paste the text.

Comment: I'm asking from phone.. but I'll try to pic a photo once I get to device

Comment: That makes sense. Alternately try concerning your laptop to the router using an Ethernet cable and see if that works.

Comment: It is.. the sitiuation now is that the pc could discover IP of router but can't resolve, ping or query domains.. it's connected using cat 6 eth cable 3 meters to the router, the same pc has another hard disk to boot with windows, and windows has no problem at all about connection.. actually my brother should be useing windows now to attend a video class.. the problem is with handling connection from only ubuntu lan and wan, even from the installed system or live iso, that's a strange behavior I have never seen before...

Comment: If the problem persists when you boot from a Live Ubuntu install USB, it is unlikely the problem is caused by any recent update to your installed Ubuntu. Please add all the information in your comments directly into your question.

Comment: Did and added some information.. seems my old iso is brocken for som reason.. I need to test another iso to be sure, and fix my system some how

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the legacy `mini.iso` which disrupted the internet connection when used over kvm

The only thing I could do is to reinstall from a fresh iso got from another device